# Tornado large file download

Tags: python, io, tornado

I'm experimenting with Content-Disposition on tornado. My code for reading and writing of file looks like this:

```
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            self.write(data)
    self.finish()
```

I expected the memory usage to be consistent since it is not reading everything at once. But the resource monitor shows:

```
In use    Available
12.7 GB   2.5GB
```

Sometimes it will even BSOD my computer...
How do I download a large file (say 12GB in size)?

Comment: You should take a look at [`StaticFileHandler`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler) and [its implementation](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/48a6bfb/tornado/web.py#L2347)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks! I'm trying that right now. It's kinda slow though (a 12.6GB zip file takes around 40min [5% in 2 minutes])

Answer (score 2):

tornado 6.0 provide a api download large file may use like below:

```
import aiofiles

async def get(self):

    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    # the aiofiles use thread pool,not real asynchronous
    async with aiofiles.open(r"F:\test.xyz","rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = await f.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            self.write(data)
            # flush method call is import,it makes low memory occupy,beacuse it send it out timely
            self.flush()
```

just use aiofiles but not use the self.flush() may not solve the trouble.

just look at the method self.write():

```
def write(self, chunk: Union[str, bytes, dict]) -> None:
    """Writes the given chunk to the output buffer.

    To write the output to the network, use the `flush()` method below.

    If the given chunk is a dictionary, we write it as JSON and set
    the Content-Type of the response to be ``application/json``.
    (if you want to send JSON as a different ``Content-Type``, call
    ``set_header`` *after* calling ``write()``).

    Note that lists are not converted to JSON because of a potential
    cross-site security vulnerability.  All JSON output should be
    wrapped in a dictionary.  More details at
    http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/ and
    https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/1009
    """
    if self._finished:
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot write() after finish()")
    if not isinstance(chunk, (bytes, unicode_type, dict)):
        message = "write() only accepts bytes, unicode, and dict objects"
        if isinstance(chunk, list):
            message += (
                ". Lists not accepted for security reasons; see "
                + "http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write"  # noqa: E501
            )
        raise TypeError(message)
    if isinstance(chunk, dict):
        chunk = escape.json_encode(chunk)
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    chunk = utf8(chunk)
    self._write_buffer.append(chunk)
```

at the ending of the code:it just append the data you want send to the _write_buffer.

the data would be sent when the get or post method has finished and the finish method be called.

the document about tornado 's handler flush is :

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=flush#tornado.web.RequestHandler.flush

Comment: hope could help someone else.Beacuse I meet the same problem now(2019).